# How to set default value in multiple select dropdown in laravel?

Tags: laravel, multi-select

```
{!! Form::select('documents_not_upload['.$application->id.'][]', $document_not, null, ['id' => 'documents_not_upload'.$application->id, 'aria-hidden' => 'true', 'tabindex' => '-1', 'class'=>'form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible select_documents_not_upload', 'multiple' => '', 'data-placeholder' => 'Select Documents Not Upload', 'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}
```

where `$document_not` having the following value

```
array:5 [▼
  1 => "document one"
  2 => "document two"
  3 => "document three"
  4 => "document four"
  5 => "document five"
]
```

In the above code I am creating multiple select drop down which is work perfectly. Now, What I want all dynamic value of `$document_not` should be auto selected I don't want to select value manually. So, How can I do this? Please help.

Thank You

Comment: According to the Form Collective documentation, the third parameter is the default value: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#drop-down-lists

Did you read the doc at least ?

Comment: @VincentDecaux according to this statement `echo Form::select('size', ['L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'], 'S')`. If I use `S` then  `Small` is auto selected but what to do for select all value.

Comment: Have you tried something like `[1, 2]` ?